# Private inheritance and virtual function

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Could someone please help me understand how virtual function works here even though the call is not via pointer or a reference?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  virtual void f() { std::cout << "Base::f()" << std::endl; }
  void g() { f(); }
};
class Derived : private Base {
  public:
  void f() { std::cout << "Derived::f()" << std::endl; }
  void h() { g(); }
};

int main(){
Derived d;
d.h(); // prints Derived::f() but if virtual keyword is removed from Base::f() then prints Base::f()
}
```

Comment: Note that the private inheritance has nothing to do with this question. Same thing happens with protected or public inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `d.h()` is not being made by pointer or reference, yes.

But the call to `f()` *IS* being made via a pointer - an implicit `this` pointer.

`Base::f()` is `virtual` and overridden by `Derived::f()`, so any call made to `f()` via a `Base*` pointer (or `Base&` reference) will dispatch polymorphically to `Derived::f()` when referring to the `Base` portion of a `Derived` object.

- `Derived::h()` is calling `g()`, which is really `this->g()`, where `this` is a `Derived*` pointer.  `g()` is inherited from `Base` and is callable on a `Derived` object.  `g()` is not `virtual`, so `Base::g()` gets called statically, with its `this` pointing at the `Base` portion of the `Derived` object.
- `Base::g()` is calling `f()`, which is really `this->f()`, where `this` is a `Base*` pointer.  `f()` is `virtual`, so polymorphic dispatch is performed, and since `this` points at (the `Base` portion of) a `Derived` object, `Derived::f()` gets called rather than `Base::f()`.

If you remove the `virtual` from `Base::f()`, then calling `f()` on a `Base*` pointer (or `Base&` reference) will statically call `Base::f()` unconditionally, there is no polymorphic dispatch performed.

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone please help me understand how virtual function works here even though the call is not via pointer or a reference?

It doesn't need to be, to get runtime polymorphism.

That's a myth, probably spread by overly-simplified claims in schools and on the internet.

Runtime polymorphism always "works", if your class is so-designed (i.e. with `virtual`).

If you store objects of the base type, you're slicing off the derived part, so you don't get the results you desire. Storing pointers is a common workaround for this, but that doesn't mean that pointers power runtime polymorphism.

Comment: "To trigger dynamic binding, two conditions must be met: First,[function should be virtual]. Second, the call must be made through a reference or a pointer to a base-class type" - C++ Primer by Lippman, 4th edition. This is what got me thinking call must be via ref or pointer. Remy's answer above also implies that it works because the call is  via "this" pointer. How do I reconcile your comment with these. Sorry, I'm still learning.

Comment: @user2696565 It's wrong. Or, at least, a different way of looking at it. The end result is the same, but I find that description to be misleading, resulting in questions like yours. It is true that every NSDMI call has an implicit `this->` on it, in a sense, but really it's just that [calling a virtual function triggers dynamic binding](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#3) period. Doesn't really matter either way I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to explain.